# How can I initialize a string array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, initializer-list

If I have `char arr[10][2]`;

How can I initialize it? How many ways are there of doing it and which one is the best?

`char arr[10][2] = {""};` Is this correct?

Comment: do you want to initialize all elements to `0` or specific values?

Comment: You may want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some examples of how character arrays can be initialized in C. You may use any combinations of the showed initializations for any element of the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char arr1[10][2] = { "A" };
    char arr2[10][2] = { { "A" } };
    char arr3[10][2] = { { "AB" } };
    char arr4[10][2] = { { 'A', '\0' } };
    char arr5[10][2] = { { 'A', 'B' } };
    char arr6[10][2] = { [0] = "A" };
    char arr7[10][2] = { [0] = "AB" };
    char arr8[10][2] = { [0] = { "AB" } };
    char arr9[10][2] = { [0] = { [0] = 'A', [1] = '\0' } };
    char arr10[10][2] = { [0] = { [0] = 'A', [1] = 'B' } };


    // to avoid diagnostic messages of unused variables
    ( void )arr1;
    ( void )arr2;
    ( void )arr3;
    ( void )arr4;
    ( void )arr5;
    ( void )arr6;
    ( void )arr7;
    ( void )arr8;
    ( void )arr9;
    ( void )arr10;

    return 0;
}
```

Also you can use initializations like these

```
    char arr1[10][2] = { "" };
    char arr1[10][2] = { '\0' };
```

You may not use in C an initialization like this

```
    char arr1[10][2] = {};
```

that is allowed in C++.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize all the strings to be empty strings, use:

```
char arr[10][2] = {0};
```

If you need to initialize them to something different, you'll have to use those values, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it as follows:

```
char arr[10][2] = {
    {"H"},
    {"A"},
    {"C"},
    ....
    //and so on at most 10
};
```